# How to RegEx value from terminal output

Tags: python, regex, macos, terminal

I am trying to get the time value from a terminal output.

```
import os
import re

cmd = os.popen('time Open /Applications/TextEdit.app').read()

time = re.search("real  [0-9]{1}", cmd)

print(time)
```

However, it can not find it.

Output

```
real    0m0.042s
user    0m0.015s
sys 0m0.013s
None
```

I can not even get the 0. How can I get the 0.042 as my time variable?

Comment: `time = re.search("^real\s+(\S+)$", cmd, re.M).group(1)`

Comment: I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

Comment: Is your `output` the contents of `cmd`? Please post the `cmd` contents

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are clearly a regex guru who does not need an increase in your reputation. But wouldn't you be doing this website a favor by actually creating an answer rather than just commenting so that it can be accepted and the question marked answered?

Comment: `real 0m0.045s
user 0m0.016s
sys 0m0.013s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demotest", line 7, in <module>
    time = re.search("^real\s+(\S+)$", cmd, re.M).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/39RD4n, if `cmd` is the contents you posted, then it should work. Please do not add code into comments, add that to the question.

Comment: I seem the output to the terminal for `time Open /Applications/TextEdit.app` is not the same as `cmd = os.popen('time Open /Applications/TextEdit.app').read()`

Comment: `import os
import re

cmd = os.popen('time Open /Applications/TextEdit.app').read() 
print ("-----" + cmd + "-----")`

produces 
`real 0m0.045s
user 0m0.016s
sys 0m0.012s
----------`

Comment: @bensd read my answer... the output of the time command you see is on stderr and inside your cmd variable there is only the stdout of your app which in this case is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `time` is by default printing on stderr and the call to `os.popen` is saving only the stdout in `cmd`. Therefore, I would suggest doing the following:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

p = Popen("time Open /Applications/TextEdit.app", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
time = re.search("^real\s+(\S+)$", stderr, re.M).group(1)
```

Thanks to @ Wiktor Stribiżew for the regex

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
time = re.search("real    \d+m\d+.\d+s", cmd)
```

Comment: Wrong number of spaces between 'real' and the time component, no? Did you test this?